# mongodb initdb.js script fails when running "use somedbname"

Tags: mongodb

When I run the following script:

```
mongo -u root myinitscript.js
```

And myinitscript.js has the following code:

```
use somedbname
db.createUser({
    user: 'someuser',
    pwd: 'somepass',
    roles: [{
        role: 'dbOwner',
        db: 'somedbname'
    }]
});
```

Produces the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.0
Enter password: 
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("352e2ff4-3c4b-4e4c-b898-b67450c13627") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.0
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@mongodb_init.js:1:4
failed to load: mongodb_init.js
exiting with code -3
```

When I remove **use somedbname** from the script - it works, but does NOT create the database, which is my primary goal. Running **use somedbname** under mongo shell works just fine, but is NOT an automation.
Any hints on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

`use dbname` is a special shell helper. When you load a js file you can't use this helper because its syntax is not valid js.

Use [getSiblingDb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/) instead in js files.

You can also use the connection string (`mongodb://` URI) as the shell argument and include the database in the connection string.

Comment: The working version of the script is:
    db = getSiblingDB('somedbname');
    db.createUser({
        user: 'someuser',
        pwd: 'somepass',
        roles: [{
            role: 'dbOwner',
            db: 'somedbname'
        }]
});

@D. SM, thank you very much for saving my day!!!
PS. I'm using a docker image for mongo, so I do NOT control the way they setup the connection string.